How to glue a plastic clip onto an outdoor flat marble surface
I’m installing balcony lighting and want to glue plastic clips to guide the cable conduit onto the marble floor. I have not been able to find an adhesive that works on these two materials. What should I be using? Are there glues or double-sided tapes that will work here?

Will this be temporary or permanent?

This also depends quite a bit on "which plastic" as some are much harder to get glue to stick to than others. Are we talking standard PVC conduit clamps, or some other plastic? There are also metal conduit clamps, of course.

The idea is that it’s permanent.

The clips are made of polypropylene.

Don't use glues use this Double sided tape.
It is super strong. So strong that it is used to mount some automotive body parts.  It will be fine for your clips.
An added bonus is if you want to remove the clips they can be pulled off and the tape removed with a little Goo-gone or WD-40.

I've used this sort of tape  for other applications.  I agree that it should be strong enough for this purpose.

Example: the 3M double sided tape used for automotive purposes (attaching urethane skirts and such).
